# How to replace a no with a word using SQL or Excel in a database or csv file

Tags: sql, excel, database, statistics

I have csv file where no represent a word for example there is one column name casualty class in which no's are 1,2,3 i have to replace 1 with fatal, 2 with serious, and 3 with slight. And there are around 64 columns with different category and their data is in number.

I tried Excel find and replace but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a case statement in your SELECT clause. I am not sure of your table name or field names, so bear with me:

```
CASE
    WHEN yourdata.Casualtyclass = 1 THEN 'Fatal'
    WHEN yourdata.Casualtyclass = 2 THEN 'Serious'
    WHEN yourdata.Casualtyclass = 3 THEN 'Slight'
    ELSE 'ERROR'
END AS 'Casualty Type'
```